# getting exception with RenciSSH in .NET5

Tags: .net, ssh

When I am adding RenciSSH with as nuget package it can make a ssh connection.
But when I downloaded the Source code and added the Renci.SshNet.dll as dependency in .NET5 it's getting below exception

```
{"Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.HMACRIPEMD160' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":"System.Security.Cryptography.HMACRIPEMD160"}
```

I tried version 2020.0.1

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. You can't use a .NET Framework assembly in a .NET Core application. What source code are you talking about? If you mean RenciSSH, why use the source instead of the package? Have you used the wrong build target perhaps?

Comment: I need to customize something.

Comment: The NuGet package includes compiled assemblies for all targets. So does the [Renci.SshNet.csproj](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/Renci.SshNet.csproj#L10) file. Again, why are you trying to modify the source code? Why not use the built-in configuration and extension methods? Modifying the source code without understanding what it does, is a **very bad idea** and *guarantees* exploitable bugs.